# JavaScript Editors for .NET Programmers

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, visual-studio, ide

I am a .NET developer, what JavaScript code editor would make sense to use if I spend most of my day in Visual Studio?

Comment: better change it to "what is a good editor" before the close police nail it as subjective and argumentative...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a .NET programmer, I would think Visual Studio 2008 -- using jQuery with the vsdoc files.

Comment: Visual Studio without the vsdoc has basic intellisense for Javascript. You only need a vsdoc if you're wanting specific jquery intellisense.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Notepad++](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnotepad-plus.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=agw5S5SgIYT6nAft7qnrCA&usg=AFQjCNFyyViE6HrPfZyDrSzazzktyAEe1A&sig2=XMNXPsXJoXtv2n83IVBMUA).Other editor also you can use is [Yaldex](http://www.yaldex.com/JSFactory_Pro.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com) and its built-in editor together with [Colorer-take5](http://colorer.sourceforge.net) plugin. Very good solution to the source code managing and editing.